# How compare NUMBER with 'TYPE IS TABLE OF NUMBER'?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have query, where need select `ID` and `name` by `ID`. First I check the `ID` using the function. In the function, I get several values ​​that need to be compared with the `ID`. When I make a check it gives an error: `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got ARRAY`

This query:

```
select o.id, o.name as value from table1 o, table2 r
where r.id IN (pkg.GET_VALUE(null, 1)) --error in this line
and r.id = o.id
```

Type which I use for save values from function:

```
 TYPE "ARRAY" as table of number(10)
```

How right compare `NUMBER` and `TYPE ARRAY`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `MEMBER OF` operator:

```
select o.id, o.name as value
from   table1 o
       INNER JOIN table2 r
       ON ( r.id = o.id )
where r.id MEMBER OF pkg.get_value( null, 1 )
```

*(You can also use an `INNER JOIN` rather than using Oracle's legacy comma join syntax)*

Answer (score 1):

If the function returns a *table*, see if this helps:

```
select ...
from ...
where r.id in (select * From table(pkg.get_value(null, 1)))    --> this
and r.id = o.id
```